# Does JavaSparkContext constructor will use all the configuration passed?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `SparkConf` object:

```
final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
```

And from that configuration, I instantiate my `JavaSparkContext`:

```
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

My `context` has a configuration that can be extracted using `context.hadoopConfiguration()`.

My question is, if I add a configuration to `conf`, will my `context`'s configuration have this configuration? In other words, is

```
conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", false);
```

equivalent to

```
context.hadoopConfiguration().setBoolean("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if I add a configuration to conf, will my context's configuration have this configuration?

Yes, but in `context.getConf()`, not in `hadoopConfiguration()`.

> is `conf.set(...)` equivalent to `context.hadoopConfiguration().setBoolean(...)`?

1. `hadoopConfiguration` is initialized from `conf` when the context is created, if you set anything after that, it won't change.
2. If you look at how it's initialized, you'll end up at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L82. In particular, to set `"mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress"` in `hadoopConfiguration`, you need to use the key `"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress"` in `conf`.